# What website do you reccomend for kearning how to identify wildflowers?

Tags: identification

Some identification guides have photographs, common names, and Latin names.

Which website teaches people how to use a kind of tree of branching descisions?

For example, we might ask,

> - Does the plant have leaves which look more purplish red than green (relativly speaking)? Yes or No.
> - Is the plant taller than your house? Yes or no
> - Does the plant have leaves which look more purplish red than green (relativly speaking)? Yes or no
> - Does the plant have spines longer than the nail on your pinky finger?  Yes or No.

Answer (score 1):

An online key is only as good as its underlying database, which is usually not as comprehensive as field guides. This means that any ID, especially of uncommon plants, will be incorrect if the plant to be identified is not in the database. This is the same for "ID from a photo" phone apps. A good key will have many decision points, not just a few.

For North America, the 'Peterson Field Guide to Wildflowers' book uses flower color and form (number of petals, type of flower, to name two) to narrow the focus to specific groups of plants. Within this organization, a reader can fairly easily come up with accurate IDs by comparing accurate line drawings and reading the relevant information about each plant. Habitat, range, and bloom time are all factors that enter into an ID. A little background on technical points (this is contained in the book) can help make the ID easier. Note that this requires reading, not data decision trees like a key.